# Rails Get Multiple by ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have a `Product` model. Sometimes I need to get multiple `products` at the same time (but the list is completely dynamic, so it can't be done on the Rails side).

So, let's say for this call I need to get products 1, 3, 9, 24 in one call. Is this possible? If so, do I need a custom route for this and what do I put in my controller?

i.e. does something like this work? `/products/1,3,9,24`

Comment: Are you talking about the controller/request level, or the model/database level?

Comment: You're going to have to explain a little more. What do you mean by "can't be done on the Rails side"?

Comment: @x1a4 yes, the controller/request level. Let me edit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think you should need to change the routes at all. You should just have to parse them in your controller/model.

```
def show
  @products = Product.find params[:id].split(',')
end
```

If you then send a request to `http://localhost/products/1,3,9,24`, @products should return 4 records.

Answer (score 9):

I would consider this a request to index with a limited scope, kind of like a search, so I would do:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = params[:product_ids] ? Product.find(params[:product_ids]) : Product.all
  end
end
```

and then link to this with a url array:

```
<%= link_to 'Products', products_path(:product_ids => [1, 2, 3]) %>
```

this creates the standard non-indexed url array that looks kind of like

```
product_ids[]=1&product_ids[]=2 ...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Totally agree. Processing this request with the `index` action will probably fit better with the rest of the controller logic.

Answer (score 4):

```
Product.where(:id => params[:ids].split(','))
```

Comment: It's important to note that your wildcard catches everything, so if you send a request to /products/1,2,3,4/edit , params[:ids] will contain '1,2,3,4/edit'

Comment: and u know that it is ok if u place it in the end